# OpsHub-012010: Processing blocked - earlier event(s) for entity 11888 have to be processed first

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am getting the following error when running a migration from TFS on-premise to Visual Studio Online

OpsHub-012010: Processing blocked - earlier event(s) for entity 11888 have to be processed first.

This is the second time i am trying to run the 'source control' migration on the same project.
I got the same error the first time after 3700 changesets. This time it happened after 5300 changesets.

I also tried to flag the Failure item for a retry and rerun the process, but I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

use latest version 1.0.1.005

Also Can you please zip up and send us the log files from location :\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs and email them to ovsmu@opshub.com
Please include a reference to this request in your email
so we will provide proper resolution to this thread.